# Floating Action Button (FAB) with ExtJS

Tags: button, extjs, floating-action-button

I was not able to find examples of adding FAB in Extjs and come up with the FAB mixin.
Hope, it will save time for people who is working on the same issue.

The FAB mixin is a reusable component that adds a floating action button (FAB) to a view. It can be used in conjunction with any ExtJS view, such as panel or form, to add a button that floats above the content of the view.

To use this mixin, simply include it in the `mixins` config of your view and set the `fab` config to either a string or function that points to the handler method for the FAB button, or an object containing any button config options.

The FAB mixin is highly customizable, with options to set the FAB position, style, icon, etc.

Overall, the FAB mixin is a useful component for adding a floating action button to any ExtJS view,
and can be easily customized to fit your project's needs.

Examples:

1. Add a FAB to a view that calls the `onFab` method when clicked:

```
  mixins: [ "MyApp.mixin.FloatingActionButton"],
  controller: {
    onFab: function() {
      Ext.Msg.alert("FAB", "FAB clicked");
    }
  },
  fab: 'onFab',
```

2. Add a FAB to a view that calls inline handler function when clicked:

```
  mixins: [ "MyApp.mixin.FloatingActionButton"],
  fab: function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert("FAB", "FAB clicked");
  },
```

3. Add a FAB to a view with custom button config options (e.g. bind badgeText):

```
  mixins: [ "MyApp.mixin.FloatingActionButton"],
  fab: {
    bind: {
      badgeText: "{badgeText}",
    },
    handler: function() {
      Ext.Msg.alert("FAB", "FAB clicked");
    }
  },
```

The FAB mixin (ExtJS 7, modern toolkit):

```
Ext.define("MyApp.mixin.FloatingActionButton", {
  extend: "Ext.Mixin",

  mixinConfig: {
    configs: true,
    on: {
      show: "showFab",
    },
    after: {
      destroy: "destroyFab",
      hide: "hideFab",
    },
  },

  config: {
    // String, Function or Object config
    fab: null,
  },

  updateFab: function (fab) {
    this.destroyFab();
    
    var config = ['string', 'function'].includes(typeof fab)
      ? { handler: fab }
      : fab;

    if(config.handler) {
      config.handler = typeof config.handler === 'function' 
        ? config.handler 
        : this.getController()[config.handler]
    }

    Ext.applyIf(config, {
      viewModel: {
        parent: this.getViewModel(),
      },
      xtype: "button",
      ui: "primary",
      floated: true,
      text: "Save",
      iconCls: "x-fa fa-save",
      right: 20,
      bottom: 20,
      shadow: true,
      border: false
    });

    this._FAB = Ext.create(config);
  },

  showFab: function () {
    this._FAB && this._FAB.show();
  },

  hideFab: function () {
    this._FAB && this._FAB.hide();
  },

  destroyFab: function () {
    this._FAB && this._FAB.destroy();
    delete this._FAB;
  },
});
```

Comment: Might want to specify the ExtJS version and toolkit